# What is the compatible Node version for Spartacus 4.X?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

The SAP Spartacus documentation suggests the below in their official GitHub page:
https://github.com/SAP/spartacus

[image]

From the documentation , what I could understand is that the Spartacus documentation was last updated on Sept 2021 and Node 16 came out in October 2021.

So is higher versions of node supported but is not officially specified by Spartacus team yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Node 16 is not officially supported due to it not being supported in Angular 12, we have not encountered issues using Node 16 with Spartacus 4.x thus far. It will be officially supported in Angular 13/Spartacus 5.x.

Angular compatibility list: https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3

The package.json including Node 16:

```
"engines": {
    "node": ">=12 <17"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for Spartacus has been updated to state that 14 and 16 also work with Spartacus 4.x and are recommended (see https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/recommended-development-environment/). Node12 will also work but it's end of life is coming soon.